# How to filter a string with php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a plugin exporting a bunch of strings from a database for me. The data returned is in a format like this

```
a:3:{i:0;s:8:"Skeletal";i:1;s:6:"Cardio";i:2;s:8:"Muscular";}

a:3:{i:0;s:14:"Access to care";i:1;s:15:"Confidentiality";i:2;s:20:"Consent to treatment";}
```

I can apply a php function to filter the data, how would I get it to return like this, using a function.

```
Skeletal, Cardio, Muscular

Access to care, Confidentiality, Consent to treatment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those strings are serialized variables.  Arrays specifically.  use `unserialize()` to get the array and then `join()` to comma separate it the way you want.

```
$unserialized_array = unserialize($string);
$comma_separated = join(', ', $unserialized_array);

echo $comma_separated;
```

edit: I think this is the simplest solution, but Obsidian Age's answer below provides a regex that will also do what you want (and you did ask for a regex);

Comment: @AbraCadaver I dunno, if I had asked the original question, assuming I had wanted a regex, I think I would have appreciated both answers -- the simpler (arguably more "correct") method, and the regex answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Haha, yes, I have seen that specific answer before.  It's *brilliant*!

Answer (score 2):

Those are serialized arrays, you need to [unserialize them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a really simple `preg_match_all()` of `/".*?"/`:

```
<?php
$string = 'a:3:{i:0;s:8:"Skeletal";i:1;s:6:"Cardio";i:2;s:8:"Muscular";}';
preg_match_all('/".*?"/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Now `$matches` contains an array that you can simply access the indexes of:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => "Skeletal"
        [1] => "Cardio"
        [2] => "Muscular"
    )
```

I've created a working sample of this [here](https://3v4l.org/EPuiQ).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Ummm...  Really, would you do this with JSON as well?

Comment: Since the asker specifically requested a regex, this may be the most "correct" answer, although a regex isn't strictly necessary in this situation.